# How to obtain relative pose wrt to a robot link using only quaternions and relative position?

Tags: python, quaternions, robotics

I need some help with this:

I specify a point wrt world(x,y,z) and reference that wrt to a link(i) as (x1, y1, z1). The link orientation wrt to world is q (quaternion)

Using this input, I want to make the point stick to the link. So if the  link moves the point will move as well. Similar to putting a mark on your arm. So, wrt to your arm, the mark doesn't move. Finally I need the RELATIVE POSE of that mark wrt to the link origin(arm)

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo I am simply trying to get the correct math background. The code is prefred, but not a necessity.

Comment: If you're looking for math help, you might want to try https://math.stackexchange.com/